# How to proceed after send_data() from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

I am trying a simple download from a server. This is using Rails 5.01, Ruby 2.24p230.

The view has a link to the controller to download data. It gets there just fine.

The controller method is just this:

```
  def download
    send_data("some sample text", filename:sample.txt)
    flash[:success] = "it worked"
  end
```

The result is that a file is named sample.txt containing the correct text is downloaded to the client. flash never happens. The view which linked to the controller is still on the screen, without any page refresh. A view called "download.html.erb" is never called.

My questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to cause some communication with the client following the send_data?  It would be nice to tell the person on the client something after a successful download.
2. After the send_data, what should happen?

Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: I feel showing your routes, and the HTTP request that you made would also help.

Comment: If you're sending data, you're committed to sending data. You'll have to do something client-side to handle the "you got it" case. Endpoints like this usually fire and then there's nothing to follow-up with, the client just downloads a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand what is going on here you have to understand how the session and flashes work.

A flash message is stored in the session and carried on to the next request. When the request is finished flash messages from the previous request are removed from the "flash hash" which is stored in the session.

```
class TestController

  # GET /foo
  def foo
    flash[:notice] = "Hello"
    redirect_to '/bar'
  end

  # GET /bar
  def bar
    flash.now[:alert] = " world!"
  end
end
```

So when the user requests `/foo` they are redirected to `/bar` and the flash hash will contain:

```
{
  notice: "Hello",
  alert: " world!"
}
```

So how is this relevant? When the client clicks the download button the flash message you set will be seen in the next request they perform. Which is not really that useful. Instead what you want to do is probably just use javascript and display a popup or some sort of message when the user clicks the download link.

When you send data to the client few will actually allow you to set any kind of redirect to be followed or will ignore any headers you send. This is because the huge number of potential annoying or malicious uses.

Comment: What is commonly done is that you set the download link target to so that it opens in a new window and use a javascript event listener to redirect the client. However this is usually annoying and causes issues with popup blockers and anti-adware

Comment: PS the nicest thing you can do for your users is just to send the download and not pester them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Makes sense.